# Как запустить и автоматизировать python файл не из среды разработки?

Tags: python, консоль, google-spreadsheet, exe

Я работаю в jupyter notebook, скрипт берет csv файл, делает преобразования с данными и отправляет данные в google документ.

Не могу понять, что нужно сделать, чтобы этот скрипт можно было выполнять не заходя в среду разработки?
А просто, например, запустив его в консоли, или, вообще, сделать exe файл, который вручную можно запустить и он всё выполнит? Это же возможно сделать?

Заранее благодарю

UPD:
я так понимаю, что проблема в импорте библиотек. В начале кода я делаю импорт библиотек и на этом этапе выдается ошибка, что эти библиотеки не найдены. Что с этим можно сделать?

Comment: Из меню jupyter notebook сохранить как py файл, потом этот файл запускать.

Comment: понимаю, так и делал. Но ничего не происходит. Не выполняется, открывается на секунду консоль, закрывается и всё

Comment: Пока нет возможности комментировать, поэтому пишу как ответ.
Есть удобный конвертер .py в exe `auto-py-to-exe` на основе PyInstaller, с удобный графическим интерфейсом.
https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/

Comment: input() в конце поставьте, чтобы сразу не закрывалось. Ну и где у вас вывод внутри ячеек был нужно будет скорее всего в print обернуть.

Comment: `UPD: я так понимаю, что проблема в импорте библиотек. В начале кода я делаю импорт библиотек и на этом этапе выдается ошибка, что эти библиотеки не найдены. Что с этим можно сделать?` - нужно смотреть что за библиотеки. Если запускаете тем же интерпретатором, что и jupyter notebook, все те же библиотеки должны нормально импортироваться.

Answer (score 0):

Создаёшь блокнот, пишешь `py имя_файла.py`, сохраняешь как *имя_файла*.cmd

Comment: Если не помог, прошу прощения